# Get Target in MethodInterceptor

Tags: java, guice, aop, aopalliance

How I can get Target object in my interceptor?

```
   bindInterceptor(subclassesOf(A.class), any(), new MethodInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
            A a = getTarget();    //how?
            return methodInvocation.proceed();
        }
    });
```

**UPD**
Actually, there is reflection based solution, but it hope that there other solutions..

```
private static Object getTarget(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    return getFieldValue(methodInvocation, "proxy");
}

private static Object getFieldValue(Object obj, String field) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    return f.get(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it just `methodInvocation.getThis()`?

Comment: Yeap. Thanks a lot. There was some bug in my interceptors and `getThis()` used to return some wrong object. Now it works well. Thanks.